# Active Reports Dynamic Data Source

Tags: c#, activereports

In Visual Studio 2012 using C#, I'm trying to set up a dynamic File URL for the XML Report Data Source.

Going into the designer and clicking the data source, the Report Data Source dialog screen comes up. When I select the XML tab, I can enter a File URL and Recordset Pattern.

The File URL is what I need to be dynamic. I need to do something similar to how I can make build commands for the visual studio projects where they have macros for sections of the path (TargetDir, TargetName, SolutionDir, etc.). How is this typically handled?

Answer (score 2):

In the datainitialize event of the report or the reportstart event of the report, you can set the datasource info or just override with a new one.

{

// namespace is GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Data

XMLDataSource xmlDS = new XMLDataSource();  // create a new one or

xmlDS = this.DataSource as XMLDataSource;

// set the fields as you need

xmlDS.FileURL = "your path to xml"; // you can determine where it is coming from
   xmlDS.RecordsetPattern = "//DELIVERY"; // you can set the recordsetpattern here 
   xmlDS.ValidateOnParse = false;

this.DataSource = xmlDS; (if you created a new one)

}

This can be done for the code behing reports (reports that are myreport.cs) in the code behind files in vs or if the report is a script (myreport.rpx), you would use the scrip tab in vs at design time, and create the stubs for reportstart or datainitialize and put the code there.